# Combobox with two itemssources

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datatrigger, itemssource

I'm trying to make a list of either customers or suppliers based on a radio button. When I bind one list to a combobox it works. When I try to use a datatrigger to dynamically change the collection to display, nothing happens.

Since the seperate list work with the non-changing combobox, I already know it's not a datacontext type of problem. I also have installed Fody Weaver to automatically make INotifyProperties.

The XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <RadioButton Content="Klant"
                 Grid.Column="0"
                 Foreground="White"
                 Margin="10"
                 IsChecked="{Binding ButtonCustomerIsChecked}"
                 GroupName="CustomerSupplier"
                 Name="RadioButtonCustomer"
                 />
    <RadioButton Content="Leverancier"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 Foreground="White"
                 Margin="10"
                 IsChecked="{Binding ButtonSupplierIsChecked}"
                 GroupName="CustomerSupplier"
                 Name="RadioButtonSupplier"
                 />
</Grid>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SupplierList}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCustomerSupplier}"
          Style="{StaticResource InputComboBox}"
          />

<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource InputComboBox}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          >
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ButtonCustomerIsChecked, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"  Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding CustomerList}"/>
            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ButtonSupplierIsChecked, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SupplierList}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ComboBox>
```

The C# (ViewModel):

```
CustomerList = new ObservableCollection<Customer>
{
    new Customer{Id=1, Name="Bart"},
    new Customer{Id=1, Name="Nick"},
    new Customer{Id=1, Name="Erwin"},
};

SupplierList = new ObservableCollection<Customer>
{
    new Customer{Id=1, Name="Rita"},
    new Customer{Id=1, Name="Sascha"},
    new Customer{Id=1, Name="Didier"},
};
```

More C# (Customer class):

```
public class Customer : IStakeholder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The ID of the customer
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the customer
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The phone number
    /// </summary>
    public string PhNr { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The VAT number
    /// can be null
    /// </summary>
    public string VatNr { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The country where the customer is located
    /// </summary>
    public CountryCat CountryCat { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A list of payments made by the customer
    /// </summary>
    public List<IPayments> Payments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: More likely you run into [value precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence) issue, move initial property assignment into style setters.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? I'm fairly new to XAML/C# and I'm not sure which initial property assignment you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SupplierList}" ...>
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger ...>
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding CustomerList}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        <Style>
    <ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

You have to move initial assignment of `ItemsSource` into style setters like this:

```
<ComboBox ...>
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SupplierList}" />
            </Style.Setters>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger ...>
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding CustomerList}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        <Style>
    <ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

Otherwise *style trigger* can't override *local value*, see [dependency property value precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence).

---

Another problem is what in style you are binding to specific element in the view, this makes it less *reusable*, you see what you have to create as many data triggers as many radio-buttons you have. Also you are using wrong `ElementName` in bindings there, e.g. it's not `ButtonCustomerIsChecked`, should be `RadioButtonCustomer` (same for suppliers).

Here is a fix, you need only one trigger:

```
 <Style.Triggers>
     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RadioButtonCustomer}" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding CustomerList}"/>
     </DataTrigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
```

The better approach is to provide a property in ViewModel (it's MVVM term, viewmodel is a class where you have `CustomerList` defined) which will be used to run trigger.

Or even easier is to to change single property which is bound to `ItemsSource` in viewmodel, this way you don't need triggers in the view.

Comment: `<Style.Setters>` is redundant.